# How to read percentage from ffmpeg command in java?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert video file to specific format by executing ffmpeg command. In that process I want to read percentage by using timepattern format. Somehow I am not able to do it.

I have tried using the below code. Specially I am getting null in the while loop condition.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg","-i","in.webm","out.mp4");
    final Process p = pb.start();

    new Thread() {
      public void run() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(p.getErrorStream());

        // Find duration
        Pattern durPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Duration: )[^,]*");
        String dur = sc.findWithinHorizon(durPattern, 0);
        if (dur == null)
          throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse duration.");
        String[] hms = dur.split(":");
        double totalSecs = Integer.parseInt(hms[0]) * 3600
                         + Integer.parseInt(hms[1]) *   60
                         + Double.parseDouble(hms[2]);
        System.out.println("Total duration: " + totalSecs + " seconds.");

        // Find time as long as possible.
        Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=time=)[\\d.]*");
        String match;
        while (null != (match = sc.findWithinHorizon(timePattern, 0))) {
          double progress = Double.parseDouble(match) / totalSecs;
          System.out.printf("Progress: %.2f%%%n", progress * 100);
        }
      }
    }.start();

  }
}
```

I am expecting a value in the while condition, but it coming as null.`enter code here`

Comment: I am using :
Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=time=)[\\d:.]*");

Comment: Are you sure that you need p.getErrorStream() and not p.getInputStream()?
Try just output raw values.  Also, put some output text examples.

Comment: there is no "time" thing